# ToggleClass not on all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a pricing table with some hover. 
You can see it right here: http://lhit.nl/lucid/

As you see, when you hover on a pricing table all the divs toggle the classes.
And thats not what I want. I want it to be seprate ofcourse.

My jQuery:

```
$('.package').hover(function(){
     $('.name').toggleClass('name-hover')
     $('.price-container').toggleClass('price-hover')
     $('.price').toggleClass('white-hover')
     $('.month').toggleClass('white-hover')
 });
```

The css is just to overwrite current colors:

```
    .package .price-hover {
        background: #008ed6;
    }

    .package .white-hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

I already tried to use $(this) but it doesn't work.

Comment: make css for hover. .name:hover{background: #008ed6;} and etc

Comment: create a class that has the on hover css and then when the div is hovered then toggle that class

Comment: Might also try using $(this).find('.name')... to target just the one nested inside of the specific hover item.

Comment: well you select all of the elements, the code does not know you want to select only the ones inside that element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.package').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.name').toggleClass('name-hover')
    $(this).find('.price-container').toggleClass('price-hover')
    $(this).find('.price').toggleClass('white-hover')
    $(this).find('.month').toggleClass('white-hover')
});
```

Comment: You could also use `$('.name',$(this)).toggleClass('name-hover')` instead of `.find`

Answer (score 2):

This can be simply achieved just by css. Why to add Js for this ?

```
package:hover .price-container{
    background: #008ed6;
}
```

Comment: That would actually make the most sense, however if the classes were to be reused on a different class set then it would require duplication.

Comment: @MCMXCII - The amount of code you write in Javascript in this case to reuse class is much more than you actually have to duplicate with different class set. So for example let's say there is package2 where we need to apply this, then you simply add it like this : package:hover .price-container, package2:hover .container{  background: #008ed6;}. Now compare it against the amount of javascript code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you that I could use children behind a hover. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use each():

```
  $('package').each(function() {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).hover(function() {
      $(_this).find('.name').toggleClass('name-hover')
      $(_this).find('.price-container').toggleClass('price-hover')
      $(_this).find('.price').toggleClass('white-hover')
      $(_this).find('.month').toggleClass('white-hover')
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to use `find` to only change the classes for elements
  inside the currently hovered over `.package`, otherwise it will
  change classes for all these elements.
- Secondly, `hover` event takes
  2 functions, one when mouse enters the hover area, second when cursor
  exits the hover area. The way you are handling `hover` event, it toggles the classes twice, once on hover in, once on hover out, so in the end leaving it same as before.

Try this code:

```
$('.package').hover(function(){
     $(this).find('.name').addClass('name-hover');
     $(this).find('.price-container').addClass('price-hover');
     $(this).find('.price').addClass('white-hover');
     $(this).find('.month').addClass('white-hover');
 }, function(){
     $(this).find('.name').removeClass('name-hover');
     $(this).find('.price-container').removeClass('price-hover');
     $(this).find('.price').removeClass('white-hover');
     $(this).find('.month').removeClass('white-hover');
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".package").hover(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".name").toggleClass("name-hover");
    $this.find(".price-container").toggleClass("price-hover");
    $this.find(".price,.month").toggleClass("white-hover");
});
```

@Spartak Lalaj As of jQuery 1.4 the .hover() may have one parameter. See https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Why do you need to redeclare this?

Comment: To bypass redundant selector detection operation. In fact, some editors (e.g. PhpStorm) may trigger optimization warning if there are unnecessary selectors in the code.

Comment: Thank you guys, it definitely helped me a lot on the jQuery side. But now I want to happen the hover event on the .order button on the website. Its actually quite hard to do. I cant do it with just changing .package by .order.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, but you can refer the parent .package from .order as `$(".order").hover(function() { $package=$(this).closest("div.package"); $package.find..... });`